# connection between html button on apache and python script

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, apache

i need a solution for my apache python problem.

I have an apache web server with a page full of buttons and they are supposed to perform different functions and actions in a python script on the server.

The page should not reload when you activate a button. Is there a way to make the button click work for python? So to say that python listens if there was a button click? But I don't want to run the webserver on pyhton.

Since I have no experience with such a complex thing, I wanted to ask for advice. I hope the problem is understandable and there is a simple solution